# Get data from multiple HTTP GET requests before returning

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following snippet of code that accepts an array of data, performs an HTTP GET request for each item in the array, and loads the returned data into a new array before executing a provided callback method:

```
function(players, callbackMethod) { 
   var returnData = [];  
   players.forEach(function(item){
       var playerRequestUrl = baseUrl+'/'+platform+'/members/'+item.blazeId+'/stats';
       https.get(playerRequestUrl, function(res){
           res.on('data', function(chunk){
               var playerData = JSON.parse(chunk);
               returnData.push({"username":item.username, "data":playerData.raw[item.blazeId]});

               //callback here?                            
           });
       });
   });
```

}

Essentially it takes an array of objects like this:

```
[
    {
      "username":"user1",
      "blazeId":"guid1"
    },
    {
       "username":"user2",
       "blazeId":"guid2"
    }
]
```

and returns an array of objects like this:

```
[
   {
      "username":"user1",
      "data": { /** response data **/ }
   },
   {
      "username":"user2",
      "data": { /** response data **/ }
   }
]
```

The issue I have is that I don't know how to invoke the supplied callback method in such a way that the code waits until all `http.get` operations have completed before executing.

How can I achieve the expected results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all` over all requests that, once resolved, calls the callback:

```
function getAllPlayers(players, callbackMethod) {
  Promise.all(players.map((item) => {
    const playerRequestUrl = baseUrl + '/' + platform + '/members/' + item.blazeId + '/stats';
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      https.get(playerRequestUrl, function(res) {
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
          const playerData = JSON.parse(chunk);
          resolve({
            "username": item.username,
            "data": playerData.raw[item.blazeId]
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }))
    .then(callbackMethod)
}
```

Note that with this implementation, `callbackMethod` should accept one argument corresponding to your `returnData` array.

Comment: Works perfectly. If I understand correctly: Promise.all() expects a collection of promises.  players.map() inner function retrieves HTTP GET data and returns data to map() via execution of resolve().  then() is called when all promises are resolved, with the result of players.map() passed to it.  Is my understanding of the solution correct?

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can test length of returnData, when it matches the length of the players you have it all and you can callback.  I also recomend taking a look at the async module https://www.npmjs.com/package/async or taking at converting to using promises and using Promise.all

```
function(players, callbackMethod) { 
   var returnData = [];
   players.forEach(function(item){
       var playerRequestUrl = baseUrl+'/'+platform+'/members/'+item.blazeId+'/stats';
       https.get(playerRequestUrl, function(res){
           res.on('data', function(chunk){
               var playerData = JSON.parse(chunk);
               returnData.push({"username":item.username, "data":playerData.raw[item.blazeId]});
               if (returnData.length === players.length) {
                 //callback here!
               }                      
           });
       });
   });
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity... I see that Promise was added as part of the ECMAScript 2015 spec.  Is counting the results how they would have solved this problem before then?!

Comment: That's correct, this kind of code is dated, I presented it this way because it's the minimal change to make callback parallel requests work, and under the hood on any other solution there's a counter, it's just hidden.  The issue with this kind of code is that error handling becomes complex.

Answer (score 1):

use async + promises:

```
function requestPlayer (item, url) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get(playerRequestUrl, function(res){
        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            var playerData = JSON.parse(chunk);
            return resolve({"username":item.username, "data":playerData.raw[item.blazeId]})
        });
    });
  })
}

async function myFunction (players) {
  var returnData = []
  players.forEach(function(item){
    returnData.push(requestPlayer(item, baseUrl+'/'+platform+'/members/'+item.blazeId+'/stats'))
  })
  var res = await Promise.all(returnData)
  // do whatever you want with your array of responses
}
```

Comment: Since this is a learning project I'm open to rewriting with async/await

Comment: I think using this method is better than chaining too many promises in some cases, and you don't need to write '.then(...)' to execute the next actions. I use this extensively in my node express servers to validate data.